# ArcGIS .NET Converting from WebMercator to Wgs84

Tags: wpf, mapping, arcgis

I have a set of polygon points that have the SpatialReferences.WebMercator property. I need to convert these points to SpatialReferences.Wgs84 before saving to a database. Ideally I would just keep the WebMercator setting, but the existing database is using the Wgs84 format.

I am using the GeometryEngine class, but I noticed that once I reload the polygon, it is off by some way. It is in a different location. How can I make sure this conversion is accurate?

`MapPoint point = new MapPoint(lon, lat, SpatialReferences.WebMercator);`
`MapPoint convertedPoint = (MapPoint)GeometryEngine.Project(point, SpatialReferences.Wgs84);`

So as an example, I just drew a polygon with points -33.9360095288856 18,391141081041, -33,9075206517435 18,390454436898, -33,9303125156119 18,423413355855

After performing the conversion, the points became -36.1141869553583 18.0832273300021, -36.0798547481093 18.0825746003061, -36.1073205139085 18.113902885547

Comment: The issue might be in `new MapPoint(lon, lat, SpatialReferences.WebMercator);`. I feel like you can't be passing the lat/long values here as the WebMercator Spatial Reference doesn't recognize lat/log. You need to be passing in the x/y of the spatial reference. If you already have the lat/long values then you are already in the Wgs84 projection and you should be able to do `new MapPoint(lon, lat, SpatialReferences.Wgs84);` without a projection.

Comment: Sorry, the naming is a bit off. I am indeed passing the x and y values to the MapPoint. These points come from MyMapView.SketchEditor.Geometry.ToJson(), which gives me all the x and y WebMercator values of the Geometry object. I want to convert these values to Wgs84 lat and long.